# Getting error while adding SwiftKafka package manager in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, apache-kafka

Getting error while adding SwiftKafka using package manager in Swift. Got error like undefined symbol. I have to added target in targets array in package manage package file but still getting error.

[image]

How to use swiftKafka library in swift?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're writing an app not for macOS, then Kafka cannot be used with mobile applications, mostly because of network switching.

If that is your goal, you should look into alternatives like the Confluent REST Proxy, and use HTTP calls to its API instead.

Comment: i think so https://github.com/kellanburket/franz is good library for kafka communication.

Comment: That library is not maintained. I would not recommend using it, and doesn't change the fact that Kafka shouldn't be exposed to the public internet to allow for random devices (i.e. mobile connectivity from any network) to connect. Not to mention, latency is a big concern